# Is it possible to submit first index field on each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is loop,

```
<% @book.each_with_index do |book,i| %>

 <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>

  <%= f.number_field :title, :value => book.title %>

  <% if i == 0 %>
   <%= f.number_field :count, :value => book.count%>
  <% end %>

 <% end %>

<% end %>
```

and my result shows like this: (can update title and number)

```
titleA 55
titleB 
titleC
...
```

Can I make first index field field changeable on each result list? so result should be look like this:

```
titleA 55
titleB 55
titleC 55
...
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<% @book.each_with_index do |book,i| %>
  <%- first_book_count = book.count if i == 0 %>
  <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>

    <%= f.number_field :title, :value => book.title %>
    <%= f.number_field :count, :value => first_book_count %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In erb, though it is a little ugly, you can put ruby in the template and use it.  If you wanted to clean it up a bit, you might look into using a book presenter that could encapsulate some of this logic.